# Add item in list

Tags: mongodb

See the below code :

```
Collection:
 [
  {
    _id: 'abc',
    UserName: 'aaaa',
    Password: 'xxxx',
    Friends: 
          [
               {
                  FriendId: 'bbb',
                  Confirm: 1
               },
               {
                  FriendId: 'ccc'
                  Confirm: 0
               }
          ]
  },
  {
    _id: 'cdk',
    UserName: 'bbbbbbbb',
    Password: 'xxxxzz',
    Friends: 
          [
               {
                  FriendId: 'bbb',
                  Confirm: 1
               },
               {
                  FriendId: 'aaa'
                  Confirm: 0
               }
          ]
    }
  ]
```

I want to  add `{ Friend: 'ddd', Confirm: 0 }` in `item _id: 'abc'`.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `$push`-Operator:

```
db.collection.update( { "_id": "abc" }, { $push: { Friends: { Friend: 'ddd, Confirm: 0 } } } );
```

Comment: Thank! Update Confirm: 1 of item _id : 'abc', FriendId : 'ccc'